# Apply class to divs within HTML being AJAX called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am appending new HTML on a load more button, like this:

```
function addStuff() {
  $.get('page-partials/more-stuff.html', function(stuff) {
    $('#load-button').append(stuff);
  });
};
```

The trouble is that this new content is being put into a container (with a dynamic height), which I want to animate down when more things are added. For this reason, I need to add a dynamic class to divs inside 'more-stuff.html', each time that template is added again.

Eg:

```
<div class='stuff added1'></div>
```

And then the next time it's added:

```
<div class='stuff added2'></div>
```

Etc. Is this possible? Otherwise, does anyone know of a solution to animate height changes from an undetermined non-zero number to another undetermined non-zero number?

Comment: Give height as 'auto'.

Comment: you can  use `transition` for `height` property as `-webkit-transition: height 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 0.8s ease-in-out;
    transition: height 0.8s ease-in-out;` and every-time when the data has being populated this transition will animate its `height`. As [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/azhef73g).

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Yes, I'm aware of these CSS properties. The trouble is that they only work for declared fixed-value height changes. The height of my container div which I wish to animate is 'auto', and divs are being added inside of it, causing it to increase in height. AFAIK, CSS animations won't work here.

Comment: Is `stuff` `div` element to add `added` `class` to ?

Comment: @JohnDoe Is `stuff` variable at `$.get()` callback element `<div class='stuff added1'></div>` ?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
var count = 0;
$.get('page-partials/more-stuff.html', function(stuff) {
    count++;
    $('#load-button').append(stuff).addClass('stuff added'+count);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually vivek mentioned a better approach but that has to be something like this:

```js
var stuff = '<div style="height:200px;">Dynamically appended div</div>'; // ajax response
var h = $(stuff).height();// find out the height of it.
$('.stuff').append(stuff).css('height', h); // after append just update the height.
```

```css
.stuff {
    height:60px;
    width:100px;
    border:2px solid #f00;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 0.8s ease-in-out;
    transition: height 0.8s ease-in-out; /* <------css3 transition to animate the height */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='stuff'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try chaining `added` function to each call to `addStuff`

```
function addStuff() {
  // `return` jQuery promise object from `addStuff`
  return $.get('page-partials/more-stuff.html', function(stuff) {
    $('#load-button').append(stuff);
  });
}; 

var added = function() {
  $(".stuff").each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass("added" + index + 1)
  })
}

addStuff().then(added);
```

Comment: The trouble here is that your 'added' function is selecting elements with the class 'stuff' after they've been added to the main page, so this function will only work once. On the second time, the 'added' function will also select the first batch and give both batches the new class, etc.